# How to turn-off/remove "server version" in HTTP response header in Fuse 6.2

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

HTTP Response from my ESB service contains below HTTP header details;

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(7.6.7.v20120910)

How to remove/hide server version in response header.

I have tried with camel- route configuration as below;

> > removeHeaders pattern="*"

But its not worked out. Meanwhile i tried to intercept the response by using cxf-out-interceptor, but Message contains only content-type & date in PROTOCAL_HEADERS.

Is there any configuration in Fuse container level to remove this header key from HTTP response?

Comment: Can you post your route?

Answer (score 0):

With the jetty component I think you cannot. The endpoint implementation adds back the three headers `Content-Type`, `Transfer-Encoding`, and `Server` even after the header filter strategy gets applied.

If you have the flexibility, try the `netty4-http` component instead of jetty. Possibly it does not add headers after the strategy is applied/you remove the headers explicitly with `removeHeaders`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your custom bindings instead of DefaultBindings provided by CXF if you using CXF as web service provider. In that case, you can remove/add/overrider certain attributes when headers are populated back to CXF Exchange from Camel Exchange.